# What are the different ways through which the fragmentation issue can be solved in Android devices, while making an Android Application?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, layout, fragmentmanager

Most of the resources on the web talk about the problem of fragmentation in android devices, but very less on how to solve it. Can anyone give some resource links/ tips so that we can reduce its effect in android applications, enabling the android developers to reach out to as many users as possible. Thanks.

Comment: what kind of issues?

Comment: what sort of problems you are talking about?

Comment: Off-topic > Asking for off-site resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Fragmentation is inherent to GooglePlay. If  you want to bypass it or make a workaround, you'd have to publish on a different app store than GooglePlay. Fortunatelly for you, GooglePlay is #13 in China, so aiming for one of the top5 might give you better results.

But this is really not something you can actually do something about. You can fix `Fragment` and `FragmentManager` related issues easily; but not the Android Fragmentation issue - because that's what (ecosystem) fragmentation really is.